# how to display two tables in Crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm stuck in displaying the fields of two tables in Crystal Reports. I'm trying to code it manually but this code won't work. It works only if there's one table to display I think.

**here is my code:**

```
''''''''''''''''connection to database''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
connectionsrvr = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=ticketing_system;")

    connectionsrvr.Open()

    If connectionsrvr.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        MsgBox("Cannot connect to server")
    End If
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sql As String

        sql = "SELECT complaint.*,errordesc.* FROM complaint,errordesc WHERE status='finished'"
        Dim dscmd As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionsrvr)
        dscmd.Fill(ds, "complaint")


        connectionsrvr.Close()

        Dim objret As New CrystalReport1
        objret.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objret
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Comment: you need to use a JOIN to get anything meaningful out of the query

Comment: even i used join the crystal report wont work. but my join query was working on ems sql

Comment: if your using crystal why not just use it to create the joins internally, and only use VB to create the database connection?