# How to display data in crystal report without duplicating the data?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a problem in displaying the data in crystal reports using left join because its duplicating my data even though I am using GROUP BY in SQL command.

Here is the list of my tables:

- table 1: `complaint`

  [image]
- table 2: `errordesc` (error description)

  [image]

Here is my code in Crystal Reports:

```
    Dim objConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim daT1, daT2 As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim activecomp As DataSet
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strConnection = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=ticketing_system;"
    objConn = New MySqlConnection(strConnection)
    objConn.Open()

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM errordesc LEFT JOIN complaint ON errordesc.tran_no=complaint.tran_no WHERE errordesc.status='On-process' group by errordesc.err_id "
    daT1 = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objConn)
    activecomp = New DataSet
    daT1.Fill(activecomp, "comp")
    daT1.Fill(activecomp, "active")

    Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1
    rpt.SetDataSource(activecomp)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt

    objConn.Close()
```

and my output was this:

[image: output]

It duplicated my errordesc.err_id even though I grouped it. :( please help if anyone knows. Thanks in advance...

Comment: you STILL need to use JOIN on (complaint, errordesc) to do what you want as earlier when you asked http://stackoverflow.com/q/21247358/1070452 COMPLAINT ought to have a foreign key to error description which appears missing from the little bit of the DB shown.  As shown there seems to be no relation

Comment: i already used join sir but the output was the same

Comment: ...so you said, but you never showed us the SQL...what column where they joined on?

Comment: do you have any idea whats wrong on this besides left join? i already used left join sir but the output was the same.

Comment: i showed my sql sir. i updated my sql query to join. please look up in my code above sir. :(

Comment: You need to provide a sample of each table's data.  Moreover, why not just create a report directly against the database?  Doing so in code is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oohh. i solved my own problem by coding my to crystal reports like this:

```
Dim objConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim daT1, daT2 As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim activecomp As DataSet
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strConnection = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=ticketing_system;"
    objConn = New MySqlConnection(strConnection)
    objConn.Open()


    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM errordesc WHERE errordesc.status='On-process' group by errordesc.err_id "
    daT1 = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objConn)
    activecomp = New DataSet
    daT1.Fill(activecomp, "errordesc")

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM complaint left join errordesc on complaint.tran_no=errordesc.tran_no group by complaint.tran_no"
    daT2 = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objConn)
    daT2.Fill(activecomp, "complaint")

    Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1
    rpt.SetDataSource(activecomp)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt

    objConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

i think that the simple way to remove your duplicate rows is changing your `strSQL`:

```
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM errordesc LEFT JOIN "+
    "complaint ON errordesc.tran_no=complaint.tran_no "+
    "WHERE errordesc.status='On-process' group by errordesc.err_id "
```

Comment: dont work sir. the output was the same. hmm. maybe on my dataset is the problem or i must link the two tables in my dataset before ill set a command in mysql